# django how to make POST request ONLY using {% url ' x' %} in HTML

Tags: python, django

Here is my views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Todo
from .forms import TodoForm
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def todoPanel(request):
    form = TodoForm()
    
    todo_list = Todo.objects.order_by('id')

    context =  {'form': form, 'tasks': todo_list}

    return render(request, 'todo_panel.html', context)

@require_http_methods
def addTask(request):
    form = TodoForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        task = Todo(task=form.cleaned_data['task'])
        task.save()

    return redirect('panel')
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('panel/', views.todoPanel, name='panel'),
    path('addTask', views.addTask, name='addTask')
    #path('delete_confirm', views.todo_delete, name='delete_confirm')
]
```

and here is my todo_panel.HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Todo Panel</h1>

<!-- Render the form here-->
<form action="{% url 'addTask' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>    

<!-- Display the todos here -->

<ul class="list-group">
{% for task in tasks %}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ task }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

I don't want django to redirect me to addTask... I want it to make a POST request. I read the example here https://github.com/PrettyPrinted/django_todo_app and he was able to do it without it redirecting to add. I just want it to make a POST request so it can POST a todo to database.

Comment: If you don't want django to redirect you to `addtask` how you are going to perform the write operation to database?

Comment: I want to. I just don't want it to make a GET request

Comment: When did you made a GET request? You are making a POST request when submitting the form.

Comment: When I run it I ran into an error and it said I'm making a GET request.

Comment: post that error here with additional traceback...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9AKTNBgB @AnuragDhadse

Comment: Don't post "Solved" or "Fixed" in your question or its title. If an answer helped you solve this, then accept the answer.

Comment: I figured out myself. it's for the people who were helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `addTask` method like this:

```
@require_http_methods
def todoPanel(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TodoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            task = Todo(task=form.cleaned_data['task'])
            task.save()

        return redirect('panel')

    form = TodoForm()
    todo_list = Todo.objects.order_by('id')
    context =  {'form': form, 'tasks': todo_list}
    return render(request, 'todo_panel.html', context)
```

This will make sure the function operation only executes when the request is a `POST`.

Comment: Hello @AnuragDhadse this will still raise an error because it accepts only **POST** request but to make a **POST** request form has to get in **GET** request so that he can submit his form and make a **POST** request

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Edited the answer. This will definitely get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

You have get your form in **GET** request and add a condition to handle **POST** request like this

```
@require_http_methods
def addTask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          return redirect('panel')
    else:
       form = ContactForm()
    return render(request,"todo_panel.html",{'form':form})
```

Comment: I fixed it. I used require_POST